# Altium bus connections with sheet hierarchy

Tags: schematics, altium, bus

I am using a bus to connect a repeating module to an MCU in Altium. I've tried numerous variations and can't find an example the same as this. I'm not sure which should have labels and which shouldn't or if they can be the same name.

What is the correct way to do this?

The actual circuit has many other connections but I have simplified the circuit down to figure out the problem.

**Errors**:
[image: New Errors]

**Sheet Hierarchy:**

[image: Sheet Hierarchy]

**Top Sheet:**
[image: New Top Sheet]

**MCU:** (Don't mind mess, just there to suppress driving force errors)

[image: MCU]

**Module:**

[image: Module]

**Edit:**

I made a mistake when creating the example circuit which @Daniel pointed out. I fixed the mistake but the original naming problem still exists.

Old errors and top sheet:

[image: Errors]
[image: Top Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be your issue. You need to put the sheet name first in the argument list.

[image]

But note that it's totally acceptable to make multiple sheet entries from the same schematic page and just route it explicitly too.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake when creating the example circuit. I've updated the question with the fix but I still haven't got the net naming quite right.

Comment: Try changing "REPEAT" to "Repeat"

Comment: That didn't change anything. I think I either have too many net-labels or they need to be different at different places, but not sure. It either complains about multiple names or duplicate net names.

Comment: @KylePennington11 You said you updated the image with the latest information - but did you use REPEAT(MOD,1,8) or did you use REPEAT(1,8,MOD) ? Only one of these is correct.

Comment: @efox29 Sorry, for the confusion. I fixed it to REPEAT(MOD,1,8) and moved the old images to the bottom.